# Conflict between packages utf8 and cite

Tags: input-encodings, cite-package

I'm trying to write a project to my qualify exam and when I use the  packages utf8 and cite to group references ([1,2,3]->[1-3]), it appears the follow message in the log file -

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8: not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.33 \usepackage{cite}

Your command was ignored.
```

P.S. Sorry about my English.

**My preamble is**

```
\documentclass[brazil,12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}   
\usepackage{anysize}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}    
\usepackage[ruled,chapter]{algorithm} 
\usepackage{makeidx}    
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{amssymb}    
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{mathrsfs}   
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{subfig} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   
\usepackage{array}  
\usepackage{geometry}   
\usepackage{simplewick} 
\usepackage[all]{xy}    
\usepackage{euscript}   
\usepackage{dsfont} 
\usepackage{enumerate}  
\usepackage{booktabs}   
\usepackage{braket} 
\usepackage{slashed}
\usepackage{pifont} 
\usepackage{cite}   
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[plainpages=false,pagebackref=true,pdftex]{hyperref} 

\makeindex

\marginsize{25mm}{25mm}{25mm}{25mm}

\hypersetup{pdfpagelabels,hyperindex,colorlinks=true,breaklinks=true,bookmarks=true,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,urlcolor=black}


\begin{document}

\newpage
\phantomsection
\tableofcontents


\mainmatter
\input{Project.tex}
\input{Bibliography.tex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is not the source of the conflict. It is probably due to an unexpected character in your `.bib` file that is causing BibTeX to choke. But what is `\input{Bibliography.tex}`? That seems like a highly unorthodox way to construct a bibliography.

Comment: Welcome! Do you use everything in that preamble?

Answer (score 2):

There is a nother character (probably invisible) after `\usepackage{cite}`. When I copied the MWE from the question, my editor showed the replacement character U+FEFF. Delete the line and retype the line to get rid of that character.